# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter implements IDisposable but has no Dispose() method

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I realise that you can call Close() to dispose of an instance of a JsonWriter, but how does the code compile with no public Dispose() method?

Comment: Because it uses *explicit interface implementation*. See https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.cs#L1192

Comment: @haim770 that's the answer not a comment, you should write it up.

Answer (score 0):

(this is what haim770 says in the comments, but to be complete)

Because JsonWrites uses an explicit implementation on the Dispose method, you need to cast the object to IDisposable to be able to use it.

```cs
((IDisposable)jsonWriter).Dispose();
```

But usually you would put such a writer in a using-block, which does that for you.

```cs
using(var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(...)){
    ...
}
```